# TikZ: What do I look up to find information on the let command in draw?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In one of my post, Jake used the `\draw let` to determine the arc between 2 lines.
Where can I find information to better understand this command? Or what do I look up?  Similar, I would like to learn more about `atan2`. I assume it means arctan but what is the 2 for?

```
\draw let
      \p0 = (F),
      \p1 = (P1),
      \p2 = (P2),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {.3cm}
    in (F) +(\n1:\n3) arc [radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[scale = .75, pos = .5, above = .25cm] {\(\Delta\nu\)};
```

I would like to understand this code a lot better than my present understanding which is center point, right point, left point, and add the rest to draw and arc where `\n3` is the length of the arc.

Comment: The pgfmanual (`texdoc pgfmanual`) is a good place to start. `Syntax for path specifications` for `let` and `Syntax for mathematical expressions` for `atan2`. Spoiler: `atan2{x}{y}` computes `atan(y/x)`, that is the argument of the point (x,y).

Comment: @T.Verron there is a small section on `let` in the manual on the bottom of page 53 to page 54.  It doesn't have much substances though.

Comment: In my version of the manual, `let` is described in detail in section `14.15` (part III). That's not longer than 2 pages, but it is more than enough for most uses of that command. `atan2` is described in section `63.2.3` (part VI).

Comment: As of version 3.0.1a, I can confirm that `\let` is still in section 14.15 of the manual. Hopefully if it's moved in future, having the version number might help someone track down the text!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `let` operation in a nutshell:

### How does TikZ read stuff?

The path operations in TikZ are based on branching off to different mechanisms based on the characters on the stream as they are read. You will find an abundance of *if next character is `c` do something if not do another thing...* An example, after finding `e`

```
\pgfutil@ifnextchar l{\tikz@ellipse}{\tikz@@e@char}}%
```

it checks if it is ellipse depending on the next character is `l` otherwise checks if it is the plain `edge` or `edge from parent` by looking at `dge` or `f` follows.

```
\def\tikz@@e@char dge{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar f{\tikz@edgetoparent}{\tikz@edge@plain}}%
```

So if you write, roughly speaking,

```
\node (a) at (2,0) {};
```

TikZ starts reading first `\node` then branches off to the node creation and the finds a parenthesis which branches off to node name reading and then sees an `a` which makes TikZ to switch to searching for a parenthesis and coordinate parsing. So long story short every item on the path stream gradually collects the necessary info. So when you want to do extra operations such as math calculations and maybe inserting an additional path etc. Something needs to stop the stream reading, and TikZ has such mechanisms depending on how low-level you want to go. `let` operation is the highest one of such mechanisms and mainly designed for doing coordinate and math computations (you can't start a new path with it). Other lower ones are `\pgfextra` and `pgfinterruppath` environment.

### OK, so what?

When TikZ encounters one of these at an arbitrary level, it stores the current path settings somewhere and starts parsing stuff inside these macros' or environments contents. Note that I am actually approximating the reality but you don't need such obscure distinctions now (I guess).

When TikZ encounters a `let` in the stream, it starts looking for particular macros in the stream separated by commas and finalized with `in`. Anything between `let...in` is scanned for whether it's a `\p...` (a point) or `\n...` (a number). If it is a `p` macro it's scanned for coordinate name or expression and for number otherwise. So if we have

```
\draw let \p1=(3,2),\n1={(3-2)} in (\x1,0) -- (0,\y1);
```

the first one is scanned for the coordinate(or node) with the name `(3-2)`.

```
\def\tikz@cc@handle@line{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\p{%
    \tikz@cc@handle@coor%
  }{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\n{%
      \tikz@cc@handle@num%
    }{%
      \PackageError{tikz}{``\string\p'' or ``\string\n'' expected}{}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Why or how is not important now. `\p` and `\n` accepts the next token whether it is a number like `\p1` or a word `\p{foo}` then the token becomes the point name for later. Similarly, `\n{foo}` becomes the name of the number as if you have issued

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\foo}{<math operations>}
```

One remaining important detail is that whenever a `\p` is found then since it is supposed to be a coordinate, TikZ also prepares two macro names `\x<p name>` and `\y<p name>` which holds the horizontal and vertical coordinate of the point `\p<p name>` so they can be used later too without you defining and extracting those coordinates.

Finally when an `in` is found TikZ stops doing this assignment mechanism and gets back to reading the original path. But this time whenever it finds one of those `\p`,`\n`,`\x` or `\y` it replaces them with the statements given between `let...in`.

A naming problem should be emphasized. This operation temporarily changes the meaning of these macros. Here is a simple example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\xf{1} %<--- xf is 1 here
\node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {Here!};

\draw let \p{f}=(10 pt,0) in (a.south east) -| ++(\x{f},\xf ); %<-- \xf IS NOT \x{f} 
                                                               % so being treated as 1cm.
\draw[ultra thick ,red] (a.north east) --++(10 pt,0);

\draw let \p{f}=(10 pt,0) in (a.south west) -| ++(-\x{f},\x f ); %<-- \x f IS \x{f}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Difference between `atan` and `atan2`

This is kind of well-known among programmers since `atan` is a multivalued function in `[0,2π]`. Example, `atan(1)` can be `45` (+number over +number) as well as `225` (-number over -number) so `atan2` takes the signs of the fraction into account. `atan` is only defined on `[0,π]` (or `[-π/2,π/2]` or any other combo.