# How does \path, and the like, parse its argument?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm really curious whether someone would care to take the time to explain how to create macros which work similar to some of the macros in the `pgf/TiKz` bundle.

What I'm particularly interested in is how to create a command that works as

```
\<csname> <content> [bare word directive] <more content>;
```

To make clear what I mean, I'm referring to how `\path` and `\draw` (among others) are parsed and can contain *bare word* commands such as `node` and `edge` as illustrated below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[blue] node (B) at (0,3) {CORNER} edge [->] (0,0) edge [->] (2,4);
  \draw  (0,0) -- (2,4) node [midway] {HELLO} edge [->] (B);
  \draw  (2,4) -- (4,2) edge [->] (B)         node [midway] {HELLO} ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I'm **not** interested in is how `node` knows what to work with or how `edge` knows where to draw to and from.

Instead, what I'm curious is how does `LaTeX` wind up seeing the bare word `node` as, *essentially*, a further command, and likewise with `edge`.  So this is a question about parsing arguments and interpreting the content of those arguments.

I've dug through quite a bit of the `tikz.code.tex` and other files trying to figure out how this parsing is achieved, but I very quickly get lost in the code.

I can't even get something so simple as the following to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newcommand\hello{Hello World!}
\newcommand\ciao{ciao?}
\newcommand\secretmessage{\ae@message}
\def\ae@message(#1)#2;{%%
  \def\ae@continue{}%%
  \hspace{1em}\emph{#1}%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{#2}\relax
  \else
    \def\ae@continue{\ae@parse #2 ;}%%
  \fi
  \ae@continue
  \def\ae@continue{}%%
  }
\def\ae@parse#1 ;{\typeout{===>"#1"}\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\ae@trim#1{\ignorespaces#1\unskip}

\makeatother
\setlength\parskip{2ex}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\secretmessage(This is my message.);

\secretmessage(This is my message.) hello;

\secretmessage(This is my message.) ciao;

\secretmessage(This is my message.);

The above should have been interpreted as equivalent to:

\secretmessage(This is my message.);

\secretmessage(This is my message.); \hello

\secretmessage(This is my message.); \ciao

\secretmessage(This is my message.);

\end{document}
```

[image]

I can't begin to figure out how to get the spaces out of the above without creating horrible cludges like

```
 \csname\space hello\endcsname
```

Though I would really like to be able to do something more complicated like:

```
\secretmessage(This is my message.) hello ciao;
```

which should effectively be interpreted to

```
\secretmessage(This is my message.); \hello\space \ciao
```

Though I strongly suspect that without the aid of further arguments to either `hello` or `ciao` such adjacent bare word directives are unlikely to get parsed correctly without an extreme amount of work.

Comment: You can watch the parsing in slow motion by adding `\tracingmacros=1` and looking in the log file. The key is using *delimited* arguments. Also, `\path` wants just to transform the code up to `;` into lower level instructions and spaces are mostly discarded.

Comment: Some brief introduction I gave some time ago http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120443/3235

Comment: Can I suggest using my own (half-working) `unravel` package as an alternative to `\tracingmacros=1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: it requires indeed an *extreme amount of work*

Long answer: No, you don't want to know the details. I don't want to write them. Really...
(**Update:** There is a good explanation by @percusse [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120443/12571))

Tikz does not use the TeX macro engine. It builds its own parser which basically processes all the characters after a given command (such as `\tikz`, `\path`) expecting some valid keywords, and checking letter by letter if that keyword is indeed present, until a `;` (which marks the end of the input for this parser) is found. It also processes specially `(` and so on. The meaning of most chars are context-dependent, so it has to call apropiate macros to deal with them depending on what was previously parsed.

To get an idea about the level of complexity we are talking about, here is a small snippet taken from `tikz.code.tex` which tries to determine if the following "token" (not in the TeX sense) is the word "coordinate". Tikz "calls" this macro where it expect a node as part of a path.

```
\def\tikz@parse@child@node{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar n{\tikz@parse@child@node@n}%
  {\pgfutil@ifnextchar c{\tikz@parse@child@node@c}%
    {\tikz@parse@child@node@rest}}}
\def\tikz@parse@child@node@rest#1\pgf@stop{\def\tikz@child@node@rest{#1}}
\def\tikz@parse@child@node@c c{\pgfutil@ifnextchar o{\tikz@parse@child@node@co}{\tikz@parse@child@node@rest c}}
\def\tikz@parse@child@node@co o{\pgfutil@ifnextchar o{\tikz@parse@child@node@coordinate}{\tikz@parse@child@node@rest co}}
\def\tikz@parse@child@node@coordinate ordinate{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar ({\tikz@@parse@child@node@coordinate}{%
    \def\tikz@child@node@text{[shape=coordinate]{}}%
    \tikz@parse@child@node@rest}}%}
\def\tikz@@parse@child@node@coordinate(#1){%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar a{\tikz@p@c@n@c@at(#1)}{%
    \def\tikz@child@node@text{[shape=coordinate,name=#1]{}}%
    \tikz@parse@child@node@rest}}
\def\tikz@p@c@n@c@at(#1)at#2({%
  \def\tikz@child@node@text@pre{[shape=coordinate,name=#1]at}%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@p@c@n@c@at@math(%
}
```

As you can see (can't you? :-)) it first check if the letter `n` is present. If it is, probably it is because the word `node` comes, so it uses the macro `\tikz@parse@child@node@n` to continue. If not, it checks if it is the letter `c`. If it is, then probably it is the beginning of the word `coordinate`, so it calls the macro `\tikz@parse@child@node@c` to continue, where it checks if the next char is `o`, and so on.

This is a \tiny part of a \Huge nightmare of `\expandafter`, `\edef`, `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` `\ifx` and `\tikz@really@long@macro@name@s`. I wonder how Till Tantau managed to keep his sanity after writing all of this, unless this code was generated somehow with a tool.

Comment: _Tikz does not use the TeX macro engine_: well TikZ is written in  TeX so it must :-) I guess you mean that everything is done token-by-token so the parsing is not dependent on a more 'classical' TeX delimited argument approach (_e.g._ `\path #1 node #2 ;` or similar). (Well, it's actually a bit more complex than that, as your exert shows: `coordinate` is picked up based on the first two tokens, so things will go very odd if you do something like `\node coward`!)