# Expl3 regex and missing semicolon?

Tags: expl3, l3regex

Try to make an answer to this question [How to go about creating custom parser in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422544/how-to-go-about-creating-custom-parser-in-latex), I have the following problem. The result of the macro seem no conform to what I expect :

```
(1:1)--(-1:2)--(2,2)
```

or there is a problem related to expansion ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makelinesegment}{ m } {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_bob_func_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([0-9])- } { \1)--( } \l_bob_func_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { : } { , } \l_bob_func_tl
    (\l_bob_func_tl)
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makelinesegment{1:1--1:2-2:2}

% If uncommented 
% Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
%\tikz\draw \makelinesegment{1:1--1:2-2:2} ;

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not expandable.

Comment: You either do `\makelinesegment{1:1--1:2-2:2}\tikz\draw\l_bob_func_tl;` or program `\pgfextra` in your command if you are going to use it inside TikZ.

Comment: `\draw` expects to see something like `(1,1)--(1,2)--(2,2)`, not the set of instructions necessary to get those tokens.

Comment: @egreg More precisely, it expects to see something that gives those tokens within 100 expansions (that could be replaced by the `\romannumeral` trick ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only going to use this inside TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_bob_func_tl

\NewDocumentCommand \makelinesegment { m }
 {
  \pgfextra
  \tl_set:Nn \l_bob_func_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([0-9])- } { \1)--( } \l_bob_func_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { : } { , } \l_bob_func_tl
  \exp_last_unbraced:NNV % this is not necessary, but I find it cleaner, correct me if I'm wrong
  \endpgfextra
  (\l_bob_func_tl)
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% \makelinesegment{1:1--1:2-2:2} % do not use outside `\tikz` or `{tikzpicture}`

\tikz\draw\makelinesegment{1:1--1:2-2:2};

\end{document}
```

If you need outside too we need to add a boolean somewhere, say it if you need it.

Comment: It's fine without Boolean.

Comment: I would personally use an expandable command to get it; using regex seems like an overkill (to mee using l3regex seems like driving a HUMMER to go to the grocery store down the corner).

Comment: You broke my hart ;-) It was just a beginner exercice to discover expl3 wonderworld, as it seems hostile for now, I took my Hammer.

Comment: What is the meaning of `\exp_last_unbraced:NNV`.

Comment: @Tarass Don't worry, it's not the end of the (wonder)world. `\exp_last_unbraced:NN` takes three tokens, gets the value of the last one, what's inside the last (i.e., expands the last one once), and leaves the first two untouched. Example: `\def\a{A} \def\b{B} \def\c{C}`, then `\exp_last_unbraced:NNV \a \b \c` would expand to `\a\b C` and then expansion would continue normally (this contrasts with `\exp_args:NNV \a \b \c` that would leave `\a\b{C}`). In this particular case the three arguments are `\endpgfextra`, `(`, and `\l_bob_func_tl`.

Comment: @Tarass See Joseph's solution to the other answer to see the expandable version.

Comment: I understood the firt explanation, but not your last remark : what joseph's answer ?

Comment: I meant https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422633/21930 as an expandable solution that doesn't need regex.

Comment: I saw this one but thaught that you indicated me a exlp3 based one. My point this days is to slowly learn the expl3 syntax. Thank you.