# How to make compact data structure without parsing in Latex

Tags: etoolbox, data-structures

Say I have 100 nodes that I want to draw with slight varations 100 times. I don't want to copy/paste all the code each time, that would be a lot of duplication and a lot of boilerplate. So instead I am considering making a compact data structure to hold the values.

The question is, what is a Latex-y way of accomplishing this *without parsing*. That is, how can this be accomplished without writing a custom parser for a custom data structure.

An example data structure that would require parsing would be something like:

```
\mynodes{1:red,2:blue,3:yellow,....}
```

That would give you a comma-separated list of `id:color`, which you could then parse.

I'm wondering though, if there is a way to do this without parsing. So something like (say there exist 100 properties `1-100`):

```
\mynodes{1=red,2=yellow}
```

But this example is too simple, there could be several values per id. So more like:

```
\mynodes{1=\keys{color=red,size=1cm},2=\keys{color=yellow,size=1cm},...}
```

This could be shortened if you had a lookup table for the properties and values, such as:

```
\mynodes{1=\v{c=r,s=1},2=\v{c=y,s=1},...}
```

That would then give you an `etoolbox` list objects to iterate over. Wondering if something like that is possible, and shining some light on how one might go about accomplishing this.

The end result would be a more compact data structure without using any parsing.

Comment: What does "without any parsing" mean? Do you search for a package which will parse the parameter for you, so you do not have to write the parser?

Comment: Oh I just meant not having to write a parser by myself. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422544/how-to-go-about-creating-custom-parser-in-latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest an `expl3` approach. We store the node data in a property list; for node 1, the property `1` will contain the whole set of data; also we add the properties `1color` and `1size` for the specific data.

Data can be retrieved with `\getmynode`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mynodes}{m}
 {
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_pollard_nodes_prop { #1 }
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_pollard_nodes_prop { \pollard_add_property:nn { ##1 } { ##2 } }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getmynode}{mm}
 {% #1 = node number, #2 = property
  \prop_item:Nn \l_pollard_nodes_prop { #1#2 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { pollard/nodes }
 {
  color .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_nodes_prop { \l__pollard_nodes_temp_tl color } { #1 },
  size  .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_nodes_prop { \l__pollard_nodes_temp_tl size  } { #1 },
 }

\prop_new:N \l_pollard_nodes_prop
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { Nx }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pollard_add_property:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__pollard_nodes_temp_tl { #1 }
  \keys_set:nn { pollard/nodes } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mynodes{1={color=red,size=1cm},2={color=yellow,size=2cm},}

Node 1 -- color: \getmynode{1}{color}, size: \getmynode{1}{size}

Node 2 -- color: \getmynode{2}{color}, size: \getmynode{2}{size}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With shorthands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mynodes}{m}
 {
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_pollard_nodes_prop { #1 }
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_pollard_nodes_prop { \pollard_add_property:nn { ##1 } { ##2 } }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getmynode}{mm}
 {% #1 = node number, #2 = property
  \prop_item:Nn \l_pollard_nodes_prop { #1#2 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { pollard/nodes }
 {
  color .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_nodes_prop { \l__pollard_nodes_temp_tl color } { #1 },
  size  .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_nodes_prop { \l__pollard_nodes_temp_tl size  } { #1 },
  c     .code:n = \prop_put:Nxx \l_pollard_nodes_prop
                   { \l__pollard_nodes_temp_tl color }
                   { \__pollard_nodes_color:n { #1 } },
  s     .code:n = \keys_set:nn { pollard/nodes } { size=#1cm }
 }

\prop_new:N \l_pollard_nodes_prop
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { Nxn, Nxx }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pollard_add_property:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__pollard_nodes_temp_tl { #1 }
  \keys_set:nn { pollard/nodes } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__pollard_nodes_color:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {r}{red}
    {y}{yellow}
    % define the others you need
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mynodes{1={color=red,size=1cm},2={color=yellow,size=2cm},}

Node 1 -- color: \getmynode{1}{color}, size: \getmynode{1}{size}

Node 2 -- color: \getmynode{2}{color}, size: \getmynode{2}{size}

\mynodes{3={c=r,s=1}}

Node 3 -- color: \getmynode{3}{color}, size: \getmynode{3}{size}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize you could use underscores in command names (correct me if I'm wrong) woohoo! e.g. `cs_generate_variant:Nn`

Comment: @LancePollard That's the `expl3` convention, holding only between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure to what level you need the `\keys` parsed, but I am sure that the `listofitems` package can parse it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\mynodes[1]{%
  \setsepchar{,/=}
  \readlist\mynodelist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\mynodelist{%
    node \mynodelist[\xcnt,1] is as follows:
     \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\mynodelist[\xcnt,2]}%
    \par%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\mynodes{1=\keys{color=red,size=1cm},2=\keys{color=yellow,size=1cm}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For example, to further parse the keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\mynodes[1]{%
  \setsepchar{,/=}
  \readlist\mynodelist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\mynodelist{%
    node \mynodelist[\xcnt,1] is as follows:\\
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\parsekeys\mynodelist[\xcnt,2]%
     \readlist\keylist{\tmp}%
     \foreachitem\y\in\keylist{The key ``\keylist[\ycnt,1]'' 
        has a value of ``\keylist[\ycnt,2]''.\\}%
    \par%
  }%
}
\def\parsekeys\keys#1{\gdef\tmp{#1}}
\begin{document}
\mynodes{1=\keys{color=red,size=1cm},2=\keys{color=yellow,size=1cm}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you avoided bracing the actual `\keys` in the node list, then `listofitems` could do it even easier in one fell swoop, rather than the nested `\readlist` as shown in my 2nd code block.

So the following code also produces the above result, using the input syntax of `\mynodes{1:color=red,size=1cm;2:color=yellow,size=1cm}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\mynodes[1]{%
  \setsepchar{;/:/,/=}
  \readlist\mynodelist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\mynodelist{%
    node \mynodelist[\xcnt,1] is as follows:\\
     \foreachitem\y\in\mynodelist[\xcnt]{The key 
        ``\mynodelist[\xcnt,2,\ycnt,1]'' 
        has a value of ``\mynodelist[\xcnt,2,\ycnt,2]''.\\%
     }%
    \par%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\mynodes{1:color=red,size=1cm;2:color=yellow,size=1cm}
\end{document}
```

With the single `\readlist` in the above code, all the inputs are immediately stored in the array `\mynodelist`.

`\mynodelist[<node-number>,2,<key number>, 1]` gives the associated key and

`\mynodelist[<node-number>,2,<key number>, 2]` gives the associated key value.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to avoid parsing as much as possible and all the values have the same list of properties, you can let TeX parse your input by using a list of macro calls as argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\mynodes[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\do[3]{%
      Node ##1 has color ``##2'' and size ``##3''.\\%
    }%
    #1%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\mynodes{\do{1}{red}{1cm}\do{2}{yellow}{1cm}}
\end{document}
```

[image]